# Append a list item creates duplicate

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I have a list of lists, where I duplicate a list element and if I adjust the initial element, the newly created element is also amended.

Is this a bug?

```
alfa = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
alfa.append(alfa[0])
alfa[0].insert(0, 'a')
```

Even though I only incert 'a' in the first element of the list alfa, this is also added in the third element.

How can I avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are appending a reference of the  `alfa[0]`  so any change in the appended list will be reflected also in the initial `alfa[0]`, you can fix this by appending to your list `alfa` a copy of the list `alfa[0]`:

```
alfa.append(alfa[0].copy())
alfa[0].insert(0, 'a')
# [['a', 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append `alfa[0]` to `alfa`, you append a reference of the first item to alfa. So first and last items are the same object. So modifying the first or the third item, will change both.

Instead of appending a reference, you need to append an new object which is a copy of the first object.
Example :

```
alfa = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
# Magic is `list()`:
alfa.append(list(alfa[0]))
alfa[0].insert(0, 'a')
# Give: [['a', 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

A far better explanation: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/13124151)